# Unable to delete item via List service

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a console job that does some comparison on documents in a SharePoint library, and then deletes some of the documents.

However, the deletion fails for some documents, with the below error:

```
<ErrorCode>0x80070005</ErrorCode>
<ErrorText>Access denied.

You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.</ErrorText>
```

What could be the issue?

I have checked the document library, and the individual documents, and verified that the concerned account has delete permissions. In fact, many other documents are getting deleted from the same library.

It cannot be that somebody else has the document open somewhere; I have not been able to delete some documents for over an year.

p.s. the delete method is called via `listService.UpdateListItems(libraryname, XML)`

Comment: The fastest way to start analyzing - Login to SP under the user under which the console job is launched and try to remove problematic file manually.

Comment: The User has Full Control permissions on the library and documents; I am also able to delete files manually.

Also, the error occurs only for some(probably random) files

Comment: If you need help troubleshooting code, you may want to consider posting your code.